# SCOM 2012 R2 Powershell script monitor not running

Tags: powershell, ssh, scom

I've created a MP for SCOM 2012 R2 that is supposed to connect to a device using ssh in powershell, get a list of files and hashes for two directories, compare them, and return a result of 'PASS' or 'FAIL'. I'm using the 'ssh-sessions' module from

http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/SSH_from_PowerShell_using_the_SSH.NET_library  .

The base management pack is from

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Sample-Management-Pack-17b76379 .

If I manually run the script from the management server, it works fine, but if I put it in the MP, and watch my device for an incoming SSH connection, nothing happens. I've tried directly specifying the device's name, as well as passing in `$Target/Property[Type="System!System.Entity"]/DisplayName$`, but neither seems to work. I'm stuck as to why SCOM isn't launching the script.

MP Xml below.

TIA

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><ManagementPack xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" ContentReadable="true" SchemaVersion="2.0" OriginalSchemaVersion="1.0" RevisionId="f9713a18-16ab-43ce-872e-41e6493ee5a7">
  <Manifest>
    <Identity>
      <ID>Sample.Powershell.Monitor.Type.MP.v2</ID>
      <Version>1.0.1.19</Version>
    </Identity>
    <Name>Sample.Powershell.Monitor.Type.MP.v2</Name>
    <References>
      <Reference Alias="NetworkManagement">
        <ID>System.NetworkManagement.Library</ID>
        <Version>7.1.10226.0</Version>
        <PublicKeyToken>31bf3856ad364e35</PublicKeyToken>
      </Reference>
      <Reference Alias="Windows">
        <ID>Microsoft.Windows.Library</ID>
        <Version>7.5.8501.0</Version>
        <PublicKeyToken>31bf3856ad364e35</PublicKeyToken>
      </Reference>
      <Reference Alias="System">
        <ID>System.Library</ID>
        <Version>7.5.8501.0</Version>
        <PublicKeyToken>31bf3856ad364e35</PublicKeyToken>
      </Reference>
      <Reference Alias="SC">
        <ID>Microsoft.SystemCenter.Library</ID>
        <Version>7.0.8433.0</Version>
        <PublicKeyToken>31bf3856ad364e35</PublicKeyToken>
      </Reference>
      <Reference Alias="Health">
        <ID>System.Health.Library</ID>
        <Version>7.0.8433.0</Version>
        <PublicKeyToken>31bf3856ad364e35</PublicKeyToken>
      </Reference>
    </References>
  </Manifest>
  <TypeDefinitions>
    <ModuleTypes>
      <DataSourceModuleType ID="Wei.Out.There.TimedPowershell.v2.PropertyBagProvider" Accessibility="Public" Batching="false">
        <Configuration><xsd:element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" minOccurs="1" name="IntervalSeconds" type="xsd:integer" /><xsd:element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" minOccurs="1" name="SyncTime" type="xsd:string" /><xsd:element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" minOccurs="1" name="TimeoutSeconds" type="xsd:integer" /><xsd:element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" minOccurs="1" name="ScriptName" type="xsd:string" /><xsd:element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" minOccurs="1" name="ScriptBody" type="xsd:string" /><xsd:element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" minOccurs="0" name="Arguments" type="xsd:string" /></Configuration>
        <OverrideableParameters>
          <OverrideableParameter ID="IntervalSeconds" Selector="$Config/IntervalSeconds$" ParameterType="int" />
          <OverrideableParameter ID="SyncTime" Selector="$Config/SyncTime$" ParameterType="string" />
          <OverrideableParameter ID="TimeoutSeconds" Selector="$Config/TimeoutSeconds$" ParameterType="int" />
          <OverrideableParameter ID="Arguments" Selector="$Config/Arguments$" ParameterType="string" />
        </OverrideableParameters>
        <ModuleImplementation Isolation="Any">
          <Composite>
            <MemberModules>
              <DataSource ID="Scheduler" TypeID="System!System.SimpleScheduler"><IntervalSeconds>$Config/IntervalSeconds$</IntervalSeconds><SyncTime>$Config/SyncTime$</SyncTime></DataSource>
              <ProbeAction ID="PSProbe" TypeID="Windows!Microsoft.Windows.PowerShellPropertyBagTriggerOnlyProbe"><ScriptName>$Config/ScriptName$</ScriptName><ScriptBody>$Config/ScriptBody$</ScriptBody><Parameters><Parameter><Name>Arguments</Name><Value>$Config/Arguments$</Value></Parameter></Parameters><TimeoutSeconds>$Config/TimeoutSeconds$</TimeoutSeconds></ProbeAction>
            </MemberModules>
            <Composition>
              <Node ID="PSProbe">
                <Node ID="Scheduler" />
              </Node>
            </Composition>
          </Composite>
        </ModuleImplementation>
        <OutputType>System!System.PropertyBagData</OutputType>
      </DataSourceModuleType>
    </ModuleTypes>
    <MonitorTypes>
      <UnitMonitorType ID="Wei.Out.There.TimedPowershell.v2.TwoStateMonitorType" Accessibility="Public">
        <MonitorTypeStates>
          <MonitorTypeState ID="Error" NoDetection="false" />
          <MonitorTypeState ID="Success" NoDetection="false" />
        </MonitorTypeStates>
        <Configuration>
          <IncludeSchemaTypes>
            <SchemaType>System!System.ExpressionEvaluatorSchema</SchemaType>
          </IncludeSchemaTypes><xsd:element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" minOccurs="1" name="IntervalSeconds" type="xsd:integer" /><xsd:element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" minOccurs="1" name="SyncTime" type="xsd:string" /><xsd:element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" minOccurs="1" name="TimeoutSeconds" type="xsd:integer" /><xsd:element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" minOccurs="1" name="ScriptName" type="xsd:string" /><xsd:element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" minOccurs="0" name="Arguments" type="xsd:string" /><xsd:element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" minOccurs="1" name="ScriptBody" type="xsd:string" /><xsd:element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" minOccurs="1" name="ErrorExpression" type="ExpressionType" /><xsd:element xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" minOccurs="1" name="SuccessExpression" type="ExpressionType" /></Configuration>
        <OverrideableParameters>
          <OverrideableParameter ID="IntervalSeconds" Selector="$Config/IntervalSeconds$" ParameterType="int" />
          <OverrideableParameter ID="SyncTime" Selector="$Config/SyncTime$" ParameterType="string" />
          <OverrideableParameter ID="TimeoutSeconds" Selector="$Config/TimeoutSeconds$" ParameterType="int" />
          <OverrideableParameter ID="Arguments" Selector="$Config/Arguments$" ParameterType="string" />
        </OverrideableParameters>
        <MonitorImplementation>
          <MemberModules>
            <DataSource ID="Datasource" TypeID="Wei.Out.There.TimedPowershell.v2.PropertyBagProvider"><IntervalSeconds>$Config/IntervalSeconds$</IntervalSeconds><SyncTime>$Config/SyncTime$</SyncTime><TimeoutSeconds>$Config/TimeoutSeconds$</TimeoutSeconds><ScriptName>$Config/ScriptName$</ScriptName><ScriptBody>$Config/ScriptBody$</ScriptBody><Arguments>$Config/Arguments$</Arguments></DataSource>
            <ConditionDetection ID="ErrorFilter" TypeID="System!System.ExpressionFilter"><Expression>$Config/ErrorExpression$</Expression></ConditionDetection>
            <ConditionDetection ID="SuccessFilter" TypeID="System!System.ExpressionFilter"><Expression>$Config/SuccessExpression$</Expression></ConditionDetection>
          </MemberModules>
          <RegularDetections>
            <RegularDetection MonitorTypeStateID="Error">
              <Node ID="ErrorFilter">
                <Node ID="Datasource" />
              </Node>
            </RegularDetection>
            <RegularDetection MonitorTypeStateID="Success">
              <Node ID="SuccessFilter">
                <Node ID="Datasource" />
              </Node>
            </RegularDetection>
          </RegularDetections>
        </MonitorImplementation>
      </UnitMonitorType>
    </MonitorTypes>
  </TypeDefinitions>
  <Monitoring>
    <Monitors>
      <UnitMonitor ID="UIGeneratedMonitor6114f31ea0204cebb73ba690f5b7bf76" Accessibility="Public" Enabled="false" Target="System!System.NetworkDevice" ParentMonitorID="Health!System.Health.AvailabilityState" Remotable="true" Priority="Normal" TypeID="Wei.Out.There.TimedPowershell.v2.TwoStateMonitorType" ConfirmDelivery="false">
        <Category>Custom</Category>
        <AlertSettings AlertMessage="UIGeneratedMonitor6114f31ea0204cebb73ba690f5b7bf76_AlertMessageResourceID">
          <AlertOnState>Error</AlertOnState>
          <AutoResolve>true</AutoResolve>
          <AlertPriority>Normal</AlertPriority>
          <AlertSeverity>Error</AlertSeverity>
        </AlertSettings>
        <OperationalStates>
          <OperationalState ID="UIGeneratedOpStateIdead1cc99f95d42dfb032788f9c21c73d" MonitorTypeStateID="Success" HealthState="Success" />
          <OperationalState ID="UIGeneratedOpStateIdbf37121688a540c3894e6bcfd1cb4264" MonitorTypeStateID="Error" HealthState="Error" />
        </OperationalStates>
        <Configuration><IntervalSeconds>600</IntervalSeconds>
<SyncTime></SyncTime>
<TimeoutSeconds>60</TimeoutSeconds>
<ScriptName>test.ps1</ScriptName>
<Arguments>pitest.utwn.net</Arguments>
<ScriptBody>param([string]$CompName)
$OMModuleName = "ssh-sessions"
$OMPowerShellKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\System Center Operations Manager\12\Setup\Powershell\V2" #Valid for OM12 and OM16
$OMModulePath = Join-Path (Get-ItemProperty $OMPowerShellKey).InstallDirectory $OMModuleName
Import-Module $OMModulePath

# load ssh module
#import-module ssh-sessions

# set up api to report back to scom

$API = new-object -comObject 'MOM.ScriptAPI'

$Bag = $API.CreatePropertyBag()

#set up connection to test pi

new-sshsession -ComputerName $CompName -Username x -Password y

# get list of files in /tmp, /pictures

$tmp = Invoke-SshCommand -InvokeOnAll -Command 'cd /storage/tmp && md5sum *.*' | sort-object
$pictures = Invoke-SshCommand -InvokeOnAll -Command 'cd /storage/pictures && md5sum *.*' | sort-object

#compare arrays of filenames , hashes

$diff=$null
$diff = compare-object -ReferenceObject $tmp -DifferenceObject $pictures

if ($diff -eq $null)
{
   $Bag.addvalue("State","PASS")

}

else
{

  $Bag.addvalue("State","FAIL")
}

$Bag
start-sleep 30
Remove-SshSession -RemoveAll
</ScriptBody>
<ErrorExpression>
  <SimpleExpression>
    <ValueExpression>
      <XPathQuery Type="String">Property[@Name='State']</XPathQuery>
    </ValueExpression>
    <Operator>Equal</Operator>
    <ValueExpression>
      <Value Type="String">FAIL</Value>
    </ValueExpression>
  </SimpleExpression>
</ErrorExpression>
<SuccessExpression>
  <SimpleExpression>
    <ValueExpression>
      <XPathQuery Type="String">Property[@Name='State']</XPathQuery>
    </ValueExpression>
    <Operator>Equal</Operator>
    <ValueExpression>
      <Value Type="String">PASS</Value>
    </ValueExpression>
  </SimpleExpression>
</SuccessExpression></Configuration>
      </UnitMonitor>
    </Monitors>
    <Overrides>
      <MonitorPropertyOverride ID="OverrideForMonitorUIGeneratedMonitor6114f31ea0204cebb73ba690f5b7bf76ForContextSystemNetworkManagementNodebddcd850a7db460a9172482041b68d05" Context="NetworkManagement!System.NetworkManagement.Node" ContextInstance="5f349164-9db8-5740-ccc7-0ce05af95612" Enforced="false" Monitor="UIGeneratedMonitor6114f31ea0204cebb73ba690f5b7bf76" Property="Enabled">
        <Value>true</Value>
      </MonitorPropertyOverride>
    </Overrides>
  </Monitoring>
</ManagementPack>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your Monitor Target is wrong (the System!System.NetworkDevice is limited to SCOM 2007). For SCOM 2012 and up, you should use the class System.NetworkManagement.Node from the System.NetworkManagement.Library.

So your Unit Monitor should look like this:

```
<Monitoring>
<Monitors>
  <UnitMonitor ID="UIGeneratedMonitor6114f31ea0204cebb73ba690f5b7bf76" Accessibility="Public" Enabled="false" Target="NetworkManagement!System.NetworkManagement.Node" ...
```

Benoit